# Український відповідник до слова "планер"

Tags: відповідник

Сьогодні на ринку з'явилася така популярна річ як планер. Це блокнот, який спеціально розграфлений для того щоб вписувати в нього плани на день, тиждень, місяць, а також в ньому є спеціальні вставки куди можна записувати різну інформацію, виписувати цитати з фільмів та книг тощо.

Ось в Інтернеті є [стаття](http://volyn.tabloyid.com/styl/iaki-buvaiut-planeri-ta-shchodenniki) (сайт Таблоїд Волині) де розповідається про види планерів. Також для прикладу наведу ще одну [статтю](https://bzh.life/ua/mesta-i-veshi/10-planerov-ot-ukrainskih-proizvoditeley) (сайт БЖ), де вживається це слово. Також мені ще зустрічалося слово "планувальник".

На жаль, мені не вдалося знайти якогось відповідника на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/plan), однак, там є відповідники до слова "план" і найпопулярніші серед них:

[Замисел](http://sum.in.ua/s/zamysel)

[Замір](http://sum.in.ua/s/zamir)

І обидва слова, як на мене, є хорошими відповідниками до запозиченого "план". Цікаво чи можливо взяти за основу одне із них і утворити відповідник? Чи можливо (хоч я дуже сумніваюся) в українській мові вже є відповідник до цього слова?

Answer (score 3):

Власне, основу слова планер - "[план](http://sum.in.ua/s/plan)" міняти не варто, адже слово цілком засвоєне мовою. Та й іншомовний суфікс -ер використовується без особливих проблем. Однак погоджуюся, що саме слово "планер" вже стає причиною розширення багатозначності:

[ПЛА́НЕ́Р](http://sum.in.ua/s/planer), а, чол. Безмоторний літальний апарат...

[Тут](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/22/) можна переконатися, що до переліку українських і навіть українських іншомовних суфіксів -ер не додали, хоч той таки -іст(-ист) враховано.

Згадаємо також, що поява "планера" в мові пов'язана не тільки з тим, що сама пристрасть до цих щоденників поширюється, а й із фактом, що найпродуктивніший іншомовний суфікс -er впливає на лексику багатьох мов, в тому числі й нашої.

Аби уникнути полісемії та залучити питомі українські суфікси до вжитку в цьому випадку можна обрати кілька варіантів, окрім загаданого планувальника:

- планник
- планар
- планець

Оскільки особисто в мене ці слівця викликають добру посмішку, але абсолютно мають право на існування, то варто на живому досвіді мовців переконатися, який із них найзручніший.

Взагалі, цей підхід вимагає добору цілої низки інших слів, наприклад, маркер, диспенсер або навіть агентивних, давно засвоєних - тренер, гравер, монтер тощо.